# I am making admin panel in laravel 5.2, how to call function inside another function?

Tags: laravel

I want to know what is  wrong in my code given below, I am make my code clean and problem arises since function is not called in another function.example my retrieve function is not called in form method...similary my saveintodatabase function in not called in form method?

there is my code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Register;

class Admincontroller extends Controller
{

    public function form(Request $request)
    { 
          return $this->retrieve($request);
          $register= new Register;
          return $this->saveintodatabase($name,$phone,$email,$course,$address);        
           if($register->save())
           {
           return redirect()->route('displaydata');
           }
           else
           {
            echo "fail to insert";
           }

    }
  public function display()
  {
        $records = Register::all();
        return view('displaydata',['records' => $records]); 
  }
  public function delete($id)
  {

    $records = Register::destroy($id);
    $records = Register::all();
    if(count($records) > 0)
    {
      return redirect()->route('displaydata');
    }
    else
    {
      echo "No record found";
    }

  }
  public function update($id)
  {
    $records = Register::find($id);
   return view('updatedata',['records' => $records]);  
  }
  public function afterupdate(Request $request)
  {
    return $this->retrieve($request);
    $id=$request->id;
      $register = Register::find($id);

           if($register->save())
           {
             //$this->display();
           return redirect()->route('displaydata');
           }
           else
           {
            echo "fail to insert";
           }
  }

  public function __construct(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' =>'required',
          'phone' => 'required',
          'email' => 'required',
          'course' => 'required',
          'address' => 'required',

        ]);

  }

  private function saveintodatabase($name,$phone,$email,$course,$address)
  {

           $register->name=$name;
           $register->phone=$phone;
           $register->email=$email;
           $register->course=$course;
           $register->address=$address;

  }
  private function retrieve(Request $request )
  {
     $name=$request->name;
      $phone=$request->phone;
      $email=$request->email;
      $course=$request->course;
      $address=$request->address;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code if `form function` is called then `retrieve function` should be called However:

1. your `retrieve function` does not return anything or change any value for `form function`. How can you know if it is called. Set XDebugger could be good for you to check. Or simple put die in `retrieve function` to see if you are there or not.
2. Chances are your validatoin is failed in your constructor for this you also need to check by either debugger or die method
3. Laravel 5 has [middleware](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware), check if you are using it to cause you never reach to `form function`